# How to do calculations in HTML forms using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, calculator

I am building a simple app that multiplies a number entered by the user by 5 and displays the result. Since, I am a beginner, I need some help with this.

Here's my HTML code:

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
    <title>Area Calc</title>
       <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style.css'/>
       <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
       <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo+2' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
             <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
            <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>

            <head>
            <body>
            <div class="heading">Number Of Persons Calc</div>
         <div style=" color: white; text-align:auto; width:400px; margin-right:auto; margin-left:auto; border:1px solid white; margin-top: 120px;">
        <form method="" action="">
                <input type="text" name="area" placeholder="Enter in square metres!" class="input" />
                <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" class="button" />

            </form>
            </div>
<body>
<html>
```

Can someone tell me what JavaScript/jQuery code could possibly take the value entered by the user from the text input element and multiply it by 5 and then display the result to the user? Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
 <input type="text" name="area" placeholder="Enter in square metres!" id="op" class="input" />
 <input class="submit" type="button" value="Submit" class="button" onClick="mulBy()" />
```

SCRIPT

```
function mulBy(){
var op1=parseFloat(document.getElemntById("op").value);
val ans=op1*5;
alert(ans); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

suppose you want to display the answer in a div having id "result":

```
  <input type="text" name="area" placeholder="Enter in square metres!" class="input" />
  <input class="submit button" type="submit" value="Submit"  />

 <div id="result"></div>
```

This div is placed just after the submit button. Now write the following code after the line:

```
 <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>


  $(document).ready(function(){

  $(".submit ").click(function(){
   $("#result").html(parseInt($(".input").val())*5);
   return false;
  });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

**Calculate in HTML without using Form and submit button**

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="area" name="area" placeholder="Enter in square metres!"
                                                             class="input"/>
<br/>
<div id="result"></div>
```

**JqueryCode**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input#area").change(function(){
      var input_box = $('#area').val();
      if ( input_box != ''){
        $("div#result").html(input_box*5);
      }
      else{
        $("div#result").html("");
      }
  });      
});
```

[LiveDemo JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3JApv/)